# Recognizing the newline character in a StringReader when parsing one char at a time

Tags: c#, parsing, tokenize

I'm parsing a text file and tokenizing it for later processing. The program reads the entire text file into memory using `File.ReadAllText()` and then passes the entire string into the tokenizer. The tokenizer places the text into a `StringReader` and then processes it one character at a time.

Right now it generates a basic syntax error whenever a mismatch occurs, but I would like to include the line number where the error occurred. Is it possible to recognize the `\r\n` sequence when processing a string char-by-char using a `StringReader`? Because I've included checks in my case statement to explicitly look for both '\r' and '\n' and neither branch ever fires during debugging. All other chars are matched except these.

Example code:  (see below for simplified version with full context)

```
var c = (char)_reader.Peek();
switch(c)
{
    ... bunch of case statements here ...
    case '"':
        ParseStringToken();
        break;
    case ',':
        ParseCommaToken();
        break;
    case '.':
        ParseFullStopToken();
        break;
    case '\r':
        ParseEndOfLineToken();
        break;
    case '\n':
        ParseEndOfLineToken();
        break;
    ... more case statements ...
}
```

That last branch in the example never fires. I've also tried recognizing `\n` and it also never fires. Since `Environment.NewLine` is a string containing two chars that doesn't seem like it would work here, because I am only `Peek`ing one char ahead. Unless the answer is to include a two-char `Peek` in an `if` statement in the `default` case just to catch this situation?

It seems like there has to be a way to recognize the end-of-line character. What am I missing? Thanks.

*Edit* In response to Steve I simplified the tokenizer:

```
public class Tokenizer
{
    private readonly StringReader _reader;
    private List<Token> _tokens;

    public Tokenizer(string text)
    {
        _reader = new StringReader(text);
        _tokens = new List<Token>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize()
    {
        while (_reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            while (Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)_reader.Peek()))
                _reader.Read();

            if (-1 == _reader.Peek())
                break;

            var c = (char)_reader.Peek();
            switch(c)
            {
                case '\n':
                    Console.WriteLine("slash-n");
                    _reader.Read();
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    Console.WriteLine("slash-r");
                    _reader.Read();
                    break;
                default:
                    _reader.Read();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return _tokens;
    }
}
```

And here is the calling code, it's just a console app's `Main` method for now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"source.txt";

    var text = File.ReadAllText(path);

    var tokenizer = new Tokenizer(text);
    var tokens = tokenizer.Tokenize();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", tokens));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Neither `slash-r` nor `slash-n` are output to the console, nor are they hit during debugging. In fact the only output written to the console here is the text "Done!".

Comment: Peek doesn't advance the stream to the next character. How do you increment the stream position to advance char by char until your reach the newline?

Comment: By the way, I am unable to reproduce your problem. Did you try to comment out all the switch case but the twos related to newline and see what happens with a debugger?

Comment: @Steve this is only a snippet inside a larger method. The stream is advanced by the appropriate number of `Read()` calls in the `Parse*Token` method calls. So `ParseCommaToken` will call `Read()` once, while `ParseStringToken` will `Read()` until it reaches the closing double-quote. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Steve updated question to include simplified switch, still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, this is weird unless there is something wrong in your file. Look at it with an hex editor (you should see 0D and 0A for the newlines characters). Or write to the console the integer value returned by Peek before casting it to char

Comment: @Steve I just manually created a `source.txt` file containing only a single newline character and reran the program, and all I get is "Done!" output to the screen. Very weird indeed.

Comment: @Steve while simplifying it further to try to make an easily reproducible set of code the cause presented itself: `Char.IsWhitespace()` returns true for the EOL sequence.

Comment: It is you IsWhiteSpace that eats the newlines. NewLines are whitespaces

Comment: @Steve yeah I forgot that newlines are considered whitespace. I posted a self-answer showing the workaround since I want to specifically handle the newline separately from all other whitespace which should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this specific issue (since I couldn't find a specific answer regarding it before asking the question myself), it turns out the call to `Char.IsWhitespace()` returns true for both of the end-of-line characters `\r` and `\n`. I stupidly had forgotten this.

Since I need to bypass whitespace but want to catch these characters, to solve the problem I just created my own private method that wraps it and returns false for either of those two chars.

```
private bool IsWhitespace(char c)
{
    return ('\n' != c && '\r' != c && Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
}
```

Inside the tokenizer's loop I replaced the call to `Char.IsWhitespace`:

```
while (IsWhitespace((char)_reader.Peek()))
    _reader.Read();
```

And now it fires correctly on both of those EOL characters separately. So writing a parse function for the EOL sequence is trivial, once `\r` is detected it consumes both it and the next char `\n` and emits an `EndOfLineToken` correctly.

Comment: Can I suggest to use File.ReadLines instead of ReadAllText? This will avoid the problem at the start because each line will be identifiable by its position in the array. You need only to change the loop using directly the char from the line strings